# Get name after and before certain character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got the following entry in my database:

```
\\folder.abc\es\Folder-A\\2020-08-03\namefile.csv
```

So basically, I want everything after the last `\` and before `.`

the `namefile` in that example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what are you asking? What about what you tried didn't work, or what about the 10-100's of examples of doing this didn't you understand, and we can try to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making use of an older version of SQL server which doenst support string_split. The reverse function comes in handy as follows.

The steps i do is reverse the string, grab the char position of ".", grab the char position of "\" then apply the substring function on it to slice the data between the two positions. Finally i reverse it again to get the proper value.

Here is an example

```
with data
  as(select '\\folder.abc\es\Folder-A\\2020-08-03\namefile.csv' as col
    )
select reverse(substring(reverse(col)
                ,charindex('.',reverse(col))+1
                ,charindex('\',reverse(col))
                 -
                 charindex('.',reverse(col))-1
                 )
               ) as file_name
  from data    


+-----------+
| file_name |
+-----------+
| namefile  |
+-----------+
```

dbfiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8c0fc11f5ec813671228c362f5375126

Comment: But  i can have multiple entrys in the DB with the same name and give the error, "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"

Comment: Can you share the exact SQL statement you are trying, by editing the question. The Subquery error is not related to the question you have asked though

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select t.*, 
       left(s.value, charindex('.', s.value))
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.entry, '\') s
where t.entry like concat('%', s.value);
```

This splits the string into different components and matches on the one at the end of the string.  If components can repeat, the above can return duplicates.  That is easily addressed by moving more logic into the `apply`:

```
select t.*, s.val
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) left(s.value, charindex('.', s.value)) as val
      from string_split(t.entry, '\') s
      where t.entry like concat('%', s.value)
     ) s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use String functions (REVERSE,CHARINDEX,SUBSTRING).

```
  SELECT
    REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(REVERSE('\\folder.abc\es\Folder-A\\2020-08-03\namefile.csv'), 
    CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE('\\folder.abc\es\Folder-A\\2020-08-03\namefile.csv'))+1,
    CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE('\\folder.abc\es\Folder-A\\2020-08-03\namefile.csv'))- 
    CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE('\\folder.abc\es\Folder-A\\2020-08-03\namefile.csv'))-1))
```

OR

```
   SELECT
    REVERSE
    (
    SUBSTRING(  --get filename
    reverse(path), --to get position last \
    CHARINDEX('.',reverse(path))+1,
    CHARINDEX('\',reverse(path))- CHARINDEX('.',reverse(path))-1)   
    )
```